# Process multiple Image files in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I would like to develop a spring batch application to do the following:

- Read a folder of pictures (.jpg, .jpeg, .heic, etc...)
- Run some logic to detect the right filename (getting the earliest date from filename vs EXIF metadata)
- Move/Rename file to target directory.

I would like to parallelize this job using Partition but here's the issue:
The MultiResourcePartitioner creates a partition per file. So if my folder contains 400 pictures it means that I will have 400 partitions. Is it okay ?

My second solution, I'm leaning towards is creating a partition to handle a certain number of pictures: let's say 10 partitions of 40 pictures each. But I kinda have difficulty to implement the partitioner and reader.

Can someone enlighten me please?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the `MultiResourcePartitioner` creates a partition per file. 400 partitions should be OK on commodity hardware.

For your second solution, you could have a preparation (tasklet) step that creates sub-folders with 40 files each and make your partitioner create a partition per sub-folder. The item reader in this case could return items of type `Resource` like the `ResourcesItemReader` for instance (ie an item is a file from a directory).

Otherwise, you should find a pattern to partition your files against (name pattern, date pattern, etc), and hope to get equal partitions size.